# "This page was last modified on" code not displaying

Tags: 7, nodes

I added the following code to my `node.topl.php` but nothing is displaying on my site. What am I missing?

```
<?php
if ($submitted) { 
  echo 'This page was last modified on ' . date( "F j, Y",$node->changed);  
} ; 
?>
```

Comment: I recommend using drupal's format_date() function instead of date().

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that content type has "submitted by" information hidden.

Try just:

```
print 'This page was last modified on ' . date('F j, Y', $node->changed);
```

And clear cache at `Admin > Config > Performance`

Comment: Thank you David.

I've cindluded the following code just before the closing header tag in my node.tpl.php file

I've also cleared the cache but am not seeing the last modified line on my site :(

<?php print 'This page was last modified on ' . date('F j, Y', $node->changed);?>

Comment: Can you include your whole node.tpl.php file in your question?

Comment: Ooops. Including the same line after the article closing tag makes the line display. However, how would I go about displaying this in the footer of each page instead? Including the homepage. At the moment the last updated line is not displaying on the homepage ...

Comment: Sorry, it is now displaying, but how do I make it display in the footer instead?

Comment: Is there a way for me to "Blockify" it?

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different approach on this. Edit the `page.tpl.php` and add this:

```
<?php if (isset($node->changed)): ?>
  <div class="page-update">
    <time datetime="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', $node->changed); ?>">Page Updated: <?php echo date('m-d-Y', $node->changed); ?></time>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```